# How to obtain, from the commandline, information from a remote webpage that makes use of javascript to display information on that website?

Tags: javascript, ruby, web

I need some help in regards to obtaining information from a (remote)
website.

As an example, please consider this university page here:

https://ufind.univie.ac.at/de/course.html?lv=300448&semester=2016S

It is in german but don't mind that; the, for me, relevant part is
"Prüfungstermine" which could be translated as "Upcoming exams".

On my browser (firefox) I see that the next upcoming exam is marked
in red colour. You can probably see that as well. It is in January
2017, the 17th.

I am trying to obtain this information from ruby, from the commandline.
Normally this works fine, using the open-uri module of ruby.

The problem is that this information on that website, appears to not
be part of the page itself - not via "view source", anyway - but
instead, assumingly, is shown by some javascript-triggered display.

So I am not quite sure what options I have to programmatically access
this, e. g. from the commandline.

I read through the source code of the different pages that are sent
and found a snippet or two that may be of relevance:

(1) First, all the next exams will be shown via a tag called 
template such as:

```
<template id="examlinelink">
  <a href="exam.html?prueid=" class="link">
    <span class="mark"><abbr title='nächster Prüfungstermin'>N</abbr></span>
    <span class="day"></span>
    <span class="date"></span>
    <span class="time"></span>
    <span class="room"></span>
  </a>
</template>
```

This is obviously a href hyperlink. The curious part is that it shows
as href '="exam.html?prueid="' but in my browser this is shown as
'https://ufind.univie.ac.at/de/exam.html?prueid=1001779&lv=300185&semester=2016S'
so I again assume that javascript modifies the href value - otherwise
I can not explain why it comes up with that longer link instead.

Does anyone have any idea or a suggestion what could be done here?

When I am able to programmatically find out the next exams then I
can obtain this easily via a regex; but I have no real idea how to
have remote pages' javascript also evaluated, from the commandline,
so I am a bit at a loss.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use something which automates a real browser like [Capybara](http://teamcapybara.github.io/capybara/). It can run the browsers in headless mode too.

Comment: You could also use network monitor (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor)  to see which js and html files are downloaded. The required information is somewhere there! https://ufind.univie.ac.at/de/templates/page/course.html looks interesting for example.

Answer (score 0):

Using Firefox [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor), you can see all the data (css, html, js and xml) downloaded for this [website](https://ufind.univie.ac.at/de/course.html?lv=300448&semester=2016S).

The `main.html` is just an empty structure, and a bunch of `html` and `js` are used to add information inside it. E.g. this [html](http://view-source:https://ufind.univie.ac.at/de/templates/page/course.html) and this [javascript](https://ufind.univie.ac.at/js/page/course.js?v=202).

But where does the data come from? There's only one `xml` file, and its size is about 12kb. [Bingo](https://m2-ufind.univie.ac.at/courses/300448/2016S).

**After making sure it's okay to automate such a task**, you can just download the XML file and parse it with [nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/).